# create user Rank system like SO with Pagination

Tags: mysql, sql, pagination

I tried my best to search but failed. I am developing an application where I have to make a system to Rank users according to their scores just like SO. After searching SO, I found this query to create rank system

```
SELECT    uid,score,
          @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM      rankTable p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY  score desc
```

but how can I make this query to return rank of a particular user like at https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2014-03-01?sort=totalreputation

I just cannot get the idea to make it.

To cut the story short, I just want to make a rank system just like SO having 5 million users. Any logic suggested is appreciated.

I am developing it on MySQL, PHP and node.

Answer (score 0):

I tried following query and it works hope it solves your query. I am also sharing dataset I used

DATASET

```
CREATE TABLE rankTable (uid varchar(10) not null ,score int)
insert into rankTable values('a',5)
insert into rankTable values('b',2)
insert into rankTable values('c',10)
```

Query

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT    uid,score,
          @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM      rankTable p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY  score desc
) z where uid = 'b'
```

Limiting response

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT    uid,score,
          @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM      rankTable p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY  score desc
) z where uid = 'b'
LIMIT 0*@PageNum , 30
```

If you are displaying all the list even then

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT    uid,score,
          @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM      rankTable p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY  score desc
) z LIMIT 0*@PageNum , 30
```

Comment: You can also use like for matching criteria e.g. `uid like '%b%'` instead of `uid = 'b'`

Comment: Well Durgesh How can I make it to return 30 users along with uid b maintaining ranks?

Comment: Updated to include limit

Comment: Durgesh it's giving syntax error and where are specifiying which user to inlude? syntax error at * @PageNum , 30

Comment: Durgesh sorry for asking this but can I store query result in seperate table to retrieve it back I asked the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22420921/store-query-result-in-memory-in-mysql?noredirect=1#comment34093946_22420921

Comment: @PageNum is only a placeholder, you should replace it with the page number you are about to display and is 0 based ie 0 for first page and so on. `LIMIT x , y` basically limits the result to return at most y number of records starting from x. Also tried to answer your second question on that page.

Comment: Durgesh I already tried replacing PageNum with limit 1, 30 in Limiting Response but that is giving 0 rows

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49799/discussion-between-durgesh-chaudhary-and-abdul-jabbar-webbestow)

Answer (score 0):

Try this query to get rank in `MySQL`:

```
SELECT t4.uid,t4.score,
case when t4.score2 = t4.score3 then @Rank else
@Rank := @Rank + 1 end as rank FROM
(SELECT t2.*,t2.score score2,t3.score score3 FROM
(SELECT t1.*, @ROWNUM := @ROWNUM + 1 rn FROM
(SELECT uid,score FROM rankTable ORDER BY  score desc)t1,
(SELECT @ROWNUM := 0) r)t2 left outer join
(SELECT t1.*, @ROWNUM1 := @ROWNUM1 + 1 rn FROM
(SELECT uid,score FROM rankTable ORDER BY  score desc)t1,
(SELECT @ROWNUM1 := 0) r1)t3
on t2.rn = t3.rn + 1)t4,
(SELECT @Rank := 0) ra;
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d48c06/14)**

maybe this query works faster:

```
SELECT t2.*, t1.ranks FROM
(SELECT    Score, @rank:=@rank+1 Ranks FROM
(SELECT  DISTINCT Score FROM    rankTable a
ORDER   BY score DESC) t, (SELECT @rank:= 0)r)t1 
INNER JOIN rankTable t2 ON t2.score = t1.score;
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/abd75/1)**

Comment: I ran your query on my current table having 2 million rows, it is taking more than 30 seconds and is reaching time limit